# Is my conjecture about difference between AI and NI correct?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

My conjecture is that AI can only run on electricity , whereas NI (natural intelligence) can only run on organic food.

If my conjecture is correct then given the food source I can differentiate between AI and NI.

What is the likelihood of my conjecture being correct ?

Comment: Why is your conjecture any different from saying that computers are not alive?

Comment: Donkey ears ago I learned about the [lemon battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_battery), in primary school.

Answer (score 1):

Human neurones communicate by passing electrical signals, and a machine can use biomatter as a fuel, so I don’t think your division works.

Comment: The same argument, from the other side: you can produce electricity (and feed an AI) using common food, which can be a fun educational experiment.

Comment: I've also seen a video of a group trying to train mouse neurons to play Doom.  So it's a biological system growing on a circuit board with feedback going back and forth between the two, being fed with some sort of bio matter.

Answer (score 0):

That may be ONE difference based on how those things *currently* work.

But the challenge would be to find some criterion that explains how those are different "types" of intelligence (or there may be no differentiating criteria, and no fundamental difference in "type" of intelligence).

Which power source each uses doesn't seem to explain much in that regard.

Also, as [Paul](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/104124/6350) notes, machines could potentially use biomatter, so power source may not even be able to serve as a universal differentiating criterion.